# can we store binary values on felica card?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard, pcsc

As of now, I am able to save hexadecimal values on the sony felica card. But if we could store binary values. The card can be more efficient in terms of memory. Is there any way to save the binary data on the card?

Comment: Any card I know of stores simple plain bytes. How you represent these bytes has no effect on capacity. Can you provide additional context?

Comment: Actually it represents our use case, We have decided to store the binary values for certain things in our backend, As some critical things are there like purse data, We need to confirm the read value with the backend, Backend sends the purse data response in binary with some CRC bits. So if we could just read the data from the card as binary, The comparison will be simple for us.